# How to migrate schema changes to SQL Azure without losing data

Tags: sql-server

I am developing an application that will use SQL Azure for the production database. I will be developing locally against SQL Express on my machine. If I make changes to the schema, how do I migrate those changes to SQL Azure but still retain all of my production data? For the initial migration I used SQL Azure Migration Wizard, but that was before I had any data. Should I make a backup of the data, recreate the database with the new schema, and then restore the data?

Comment: That's a *generic* question, not related to a specific RDBMS product, much less its hosting environment.

Comment: Good point. I have removed the "azure" tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think that its a general schema versioning question. One possible solution is having migration scripts that you write and test during development and run on production during deployment phase. Entitiy Framework offers migrations as one of it features. My current prefered tool is FluentMigrator. I works for Azure Sql as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to migrate changes to SQL Server but still retain all of your production data, it is highly recommended that you version your database schema. This also applies to SQL Azure and all other RDBMSs.

This is very important when there are several developers working on a project but I believe it is also advantageous when you are working on a project by yourself.

RoundhousE is one of several simple tools you can use to achieve database versioning. It served us well for this purpose for the past 4 years: https://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/

Comment: Do you have experience of using RH with SQL Azure?